# Netbeans PHP Include Path seems unused, either Project or Global

Tags: php, netbeans, include-path

I recently converted from Eclipse PDT to NetBeans and I am having trouble with NetBeans' include path.  Whether I set it globally or per project, it seems to be unused and totally ignored.

Working within a project, I set it through Properties.  Working globally, I set it through Tools Options.  Either way, I see all my settings under the project's Include Path.  If I set it both places, I see both of them in the project's Include Path.  However, nothing is ever found within these paths.

If I add the path to the PHP.INI include_path variable, everything works fine.  So, I know the paths are being searched and the includes are being found through PHP.  Of course, that's a heck of way to build a project.

Since I don't know NetBeans very well, I assume that I missed something there.  What do I need to do to enable the NetBeans PHP Include Path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans needed configured under the Project Properties for PHPUnit to use the Bootstrap program and the XML code.  That information is needed to load the Namespace and Class information to make the project run.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Include Path option in Netbeans is only used by Netbeans to help it during code completion and file navigation. You will still need to set the Include path in your PHP.ini file if the script that you are running requires it.

Comment: That I understand very well and would accept if it did that.  It isn't doing that at all.  That was my question, why isn't NB include path helping during code completion.