# NetBeans Include Path is not being searched entirely, whether it be project, global or PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, include-path

I am having a great deal of trouble with NetBeans 7.2.1 using PHP and the Include Path.  This may or may not be related to [Netbeans PHP Include Path seems unused, either Project or Global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106104/netbeans-php-include-path-seems-unused-either-project-or-global) where I state that NetBeans is not using its Project or Global Include Path.  However, in this case, NetBeans is not searching the entire PHP Include_Path variable.

The PHP Include_Path is listed in the error messages. The file AutoloaderFactory.php is in 
D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Loader;

However, when I try to use NetBeans/Tools/Create PHPUnit Tests, I receive a series of warning and error messages saying that AutoloaderFactory.php is not found.  These messages search only three of the provided libraries which do not include the library with the required class.

As a NetBeans noob, I am obviously not understanding something about it.  But, I can't build my project because it won't find the required classes no matter what I do, including using Project, Globabl and PHP Include Paths.  Can someone help me?

The error messages are included below.  Thanks...RG

```
PHPUnit Skeleton Generator 1.2.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Warning: include(D:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\init_autoloader.php on line 38

Call Stack:
    0.0007     321856   1. {main}() K:\phpunit-skelgen:0
    0.0062     472944   2. SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command::main() K:\phpunit-skelgen:45
    0.0167     980480   3. ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command.php:171
    0.0167     980936   4. SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\TestGenerator->__construct() K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command.php:171
    0.0178     987216   5. include_once('D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php') K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\TestGenerator.php:125
    0.0213     993680   6. require_once('D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\init_autoloader.php') D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:4


Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\PHP\Includes;D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial;D:\PHP\ZendProjects\htdocs\Includes;D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library;D:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library;K:\pear') in D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\init_autoloader.php on line 38

Call Stack:
    0.0007     321856   1. {main}() K:\phpunit-skelgen:0
    0.0062     472944   2. SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command::main() K:\phpunit-skelgen:45
    0.0167     980480   3. ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command.php:171
    0.0167     980936   4. SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\TestGenerator->__construct() K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command.php:171
    0.0178     987216   5. include_once('D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php') K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\TestGenerator.php:125
    0.0213     993680   6. require_once('D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\init_autoloader.php') D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:4


Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory' not found in D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\init_autoloader.php on line 39

Call Stack:
    0.0007     321856   1. {main}() K:\phpunit-skelgen:0
    0.0062     472944   2. SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command::main() K:\phpunit-skelgen:45
    0.0167     980480   3. ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command.php:171
    0.0167     980936   4. SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\TestGenerator->__construct() K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\Command.php:171
    0.0178     987216   5. include_once('D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php') K:\pear\SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator\TestGenerator.php:125
    0.0213     993680   6. require_once('D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\init_autoloader.php') D:\PHP\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally purged NetBeans and reinstalled it.  That included doing a registry clean after uninstalling NetBeans.  At this point, the PHP Include_Path is being searched.  I do not know whether or not the NetBeans Include_Path is being searched but that is another problem and I am not even sure why I should care since that won't matter after implementation.  I'd be glad to hear a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Netbeans, search worked for me, Netbeans 7.4.